# Provide employee name whose DeptNo 2 and do not include who works more than 1 department

Tags: sql

Provide employee name whose DeptNo 2 and do not include who works more than 1 department

```
EmployeName DeptNo 
-------------------
AA            1 
AA            2 
BB            2 
CC            1 
CC            2 
DD            2
```

Expecting Results:


EmployeeName 
BB
DD

Comment: And what have you tried?  We aren't here to do your work for you.

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, HAVING and COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to assert that the employee doesnt have any other department.

```
select *
from your_table t
where deptno = 2
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from your_table t2
        where t.employename = t2.employename
            and t2.deptno <> 2
        );
```

If you just need the employeeName, use aggregation:

```
select employename
from your_table
group by employename
having count(distinct deptno) = 1
    and max(deptno) = 2
```

Comment: @Ramesh - Glad to help out. :)